How to assign a permission set to multiple users at the same time
I want to assign a permission set to 2000 users. I want to know if there is any way I can do it at the same time, instead of doing it manually one by one?

As per this documentation,

Assign a Permission Set to Multiple Users
Assign a permission set to one or more users from any permission set page.

From Setup, in the Quick Find box, enter Permission Sets, and then click Permission Sets.
Select the permission set that you want to assign to users.
Click Manage Assignments and then Add Assignments.
Select the checkboxes next to the names of the users you want assigned to the permission set, and click Next.
Optionally, select an expiration date for the user assignment to expire. For more information, see Set Assignment Expiration Details
for Users in Permission Sets and Permission Set Groups in Salesforce
Help.
Click Assign.

Messages confirm success or indicate if a user doesn’t have the
appropriate licenses for assignment.


